# How to pass multiple values for a ListField in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, listfield

I want to use a [`ListField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield) in one of my serializers. However, I can't figure out how to pass multiple values for such fields via a [Browsable API](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/) form. I've tried using `"value1, value2"` or `[value1, value2]` but nothing seems to work. Any help?

Comment: Providing no values via the HTML form (i.e. an empty field) also doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Browsable API doesn't support submitting multiple values for a `ListField` via an HTML form at the moment. There's an open [pull request](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/4029) to address this issue. In the meantime, you can use the 'Raw data' tab to submit the values as JSON data.